# Is there a way to customize the default progress bar (circular, not horizontal), with out using drawable resources?

Tags: android, android-widget, progressdialog, android-custom-view, android-progressbar

I am just wondering if there is a simple way to customize the default circular progress bar provided in android.

Let me clarify the question.

I just want a circular shape showing some dynamism representing progress (network connection) as shown on many apps, below the text displaying my application name in full screen.

What I've tried.

1) Using a ProgressDialog. I could add the title of the app successfully and got the spinner(circle) right. But could not place it on horizontal center it on the dialog. It was always displayed on the left. Then I came to know from some post that it is not possible to customize that way. Is it true? I am not sure. But I did not found any suitable API for doing that.

2) Next I tried a custom dialog with a progressbar in it. I change the background of the dialog, added my app title text and made it full screen. Below is the xml layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/bgcolor">

    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MY APP NAME"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"  
        android:textSize="25sp" 
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp" />


     <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/login_progressbar" 
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  />"


</LinearLayout>
```

in activity code i have created the dialog like:

```
 dialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_NoActionBar_Fullscreen);
```

And I almost achieved what I want but not 100%. I got a non horizontal progress bar. But its not a simple circular shape as displayed on a gingerbread phone. Its like two bars and a circle being displaced alternatively.

But in a jellybean tablet, it's like a rotating circle, the way I want. This seems to be device/app theme related issue.

So, how can I get a customized uniform look on all devices(And I don't want to use image for this) like the below images:

[image] or [image]

**UPDATE:**

The issue related to difference in behavior on jelly bean tab and gingerbread phone turned out to be a funny thing.

By changing `android:layout_width="match_parent"` to `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` in the xml layout solved it. In phone the view (spinner) was stretching extra to match parent so was the behavior. But in tab, though it was matching the parent, any how it managed to get displayed as expected, perhaps due to lots of screen space. Still I think there should be some easy way to customize ProgressBar or ProgressDialog in android.

Some link or reference regarding more details on **style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"** would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following simple solution nicely working (copying the code here in case the provided link stops working at one point):

Create a drawable resource e.g. **/res/drawable/progressbar_custom.xml** and add XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="4000"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="720" >

<shape
    android:innerRadius="20dp"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thickness="4dp"
    android:useLevel="false" >
    <size
        android:height="48dp"
        android:width="48dp" />

    <gradient
        android:centerColor="#80ffffff"
        android:centerY="0.5"
        android:endColor="#ffffffff"
        android:startColor="#00ffffff"
        android:type="sweep"
        android:useLevel="false" />
</shape>
```

Use as:

```
<ProgressBar
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progressbar_custom" />
```

For a different size calculate the inner ring by dividing the size by two and subtract the thickness. In this case you also have to use the same size for the layout_width & layout_height in the layout.

More details on duration on http://codebin.co.uk/blog/custom-indeterminate-progressbar-on-android/

Answer (score 0):

you can find many samples related to **making circular bar in android**

[android hollow circular bar](https://github.com/passsy/android-HoloCircularProgressBar)

[circular seek bar](https://github.com/RaghavSood/AndroidCircularSeekBar)

i had customized that hollowcircular bar project to a little bit simpler to be used further .

my android samples:

1. https://github.com/shujat89/Android/tree/master/myandroid%20practices/MyCircularbar
2. https://github.com/shujat89/Android